# copy files with folders

Tags: emacs, dired

How to copy selected files with folders in emacs `dired-mode`?
The problem I've faced is the next one: when I'm pressing the 'C' button to copy selected files with folders to an other folder, I'm pointing dir, and then emacs starts to copy files (files are copied OK) but then content of selected folders - not folders actually!..

Initial dirs content:

[image: Initial dirs content]

Ready to copy:

[image: Ready to copy]

Press C:

[image: Pressed C]

Press Enter:

[image: Pressed Enter]

Press y:

[image: Pressed y]

Press g on both frames:

[image: Pressed g on both frames]

As you can see - the dir `1` wasn't copyed to dir `2`,  but only it's content. This couses a problem when copying a selection with files and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(require 'ls-lisp)
(setq ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program nil)
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I mark a directory named `a` which has files `1`, `2` and `3` and copy it to another directory named `b` then after I copy the directory `b`, it contains a directory named `a` which has files `1`, `2` and `3`.

This seems like it has the same behavior as `cp`. Is that not the behavior you see?

Comment: I use `(setq dired-dwim-target t)`. Move cursor to the one folder in a 1st frame, set the 2nd frame to an appropriate folder, then in frame 1 press the 'C' button - and emacs trying to overwrite my target folder in frame 2 instead of copying into.

Comment: Even with setting `dired-dwin-target` I get the behavior I mentioned before, including the question about recursive copies. I don't believe you :) Can you try in a test directory and list the output of ls before and after?

Comment: I've checked twice - on SuSe linux and on Mac OSX. When I'm trying to copy dir - emacs wants to overwrite target dir with copied one.

Comment: @egor7 it is not clear what you mean by "overwrite target dir with copied one"; that is why I asked you to edit your question and include directory listing. I am pretty sure this is error in your understanding but without more data I can't help.

Comment: In the third screenshot emacs asks me `Copy 1 to` instead of `Copy 1/ to`. On the next screen it asks me whether I want recursive copies. I find it strange that it says `Copy: 1 file` and also the file named `2`. Are you sharing the same init files across the versions and OSs? It may be worthwhile to try with `emacs -q`. If that doesn't help then I guess you need to debug the function.

Answer (score 0):

Weird behavoir. I agree with Miserable Variable, it should be exactly same as `cp`.

Please give your emacs version. And I suggest you directly run `emacs -Q` without loadding other settings in order to figure out the root cause.

My Emacs (v23.3.1) will prompt `Recursive copies of /path/to/1? (yes or no)`, after you press <kbd>RET</kbd> in the step of your third picture.

Comment: Without loading other settings `emacs -Q` I've got the next one message `Copy '/Users/egor/tmp/copying/1' to '/Users/egor/tmp/copying/2/1' failed:
(file-error Non-regular file is a directory /Users/egor/tmp/copying/1)`

Comment: Version: Emacs 23.4.1 - all the same as described above.